# Simple drawing with Quartz - Core Graphics

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I want to draw a rectangle with the top-left corner rounded with 3 sub-spaces in it. Something like this:

```
 _______
|_|_____|
|       |
|_______|
```

But for some reason I cannot get the inner two lines drawn.

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
float cornerRadius = 25.0;
float w = self.bounds.size.width;
float h = self.bounds.size.height;
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, cornerRadius, 0);
CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, 0, 0, 0, cornerRadius);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0, h);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, w, h);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, w, 0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, cornerRadius, 0);

//drawing settings
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.5);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor white].CGColor); 

//draw rectangle
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);

//draw title/label partition
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, TITLE_HEIGHT, 0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, TITLE_HEIGHT, TITLE_HEIGHT);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

//draw title/content partition
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, TITLE_HEIGHT);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, TITLE_HEIGHT);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

I wonder what am I mistaking here... ;(

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you have TITLE_HEIGHT defined as? If it were 0, then that would explain observed behavior...

Comment: You can cut out the first `CGContextStrokePath`. Each `moveto` starts a subpath; the current path (or a CGPath object) can contain multiple subpaths. The second `CGContextStrokePath`, once it's alone, will draw both of them.

Comment: Your code works for me once I define TITLE_HEIGHT and fix typo "[UIColor white]" ==>> "[UIColor whiteColor]"

Comment: @westsider Sorry... what a silly mistake. I forgot that I should do self.bounds.size.height*TITLE_HEIGHT instead of simple TITLE_HEIGHT. @Peter thanks for the advice ;)

Comment: nacho4d, what exactly do you mean by “I cannot”? What happens instead? A syntax error? Bogus output? An exception? A crash?

Comment: nacho4d: Why that multiplication? Is `TITLE_HEIGHT` supposed to be a fraction rather than an absolute number of points? (This is why it's good to include the definitions of these constants, and to name everything descriptively.)

Comment: Peter Hosey, yes... since I am drawing this for various sizes, TITLE_HEIGHT needs to be a relative value. I just simply forgot that and I the lines I was drawing were to small and up to be visible. Now its solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment out the CGContextSetFillColorWithColor line for a while - maybe the rectangle is overlapping those lines?

Comment: Later drawing overlaps earlier drawing, not the other way around.