# Change fill color of a part of a combined path with animation?

Tags: ios, animation, uibezierpath, cashapelayer, cgpath

In simple words only part of my icon must change color at some event.

I drawing an icon with curves inside an `UIView`. The drawing boilds
down to combining several paths together like this (swift code):

```
let combinedPath = CGPathCreateMutableCopy(bezierPath.CGPath)
CGPathAddPath(combinedPath, nil, bezier2Path.CGPath);
CGPathAddPath(combinedPath, nil, bezier3Path.CGPath);
```

Then I'm adding the combined path to the UIView like this (obj-c, sorry for
the mix):

```
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.frame = self.bounds;
shapeLayer.path = combinedPath;
self.layer.mask = shapeLayer;
```

And now at some point in time I want to change the fill color of
only one `bezierPath` with animation. How can I do this?

Comment: An excellent way is using CAShapeLayer, which you can use to change its fill color in an animation. Please refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4129155/2631081

Answer (score 0):

You can clean the current mask, and redraw any of the bezierpath with stroke/fill color and combine them together, and set it again. And for drawing animation, you can refer to [How to Animate CoreGraphics Drawing of Shape Using CAKeyframeAnimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762236/how-to-animate-coregraphics-drawing-of-shape-using-cakeyframeanimation)